# Problem with ATtiny85 and RF modules

Tags: attiny

I am doing a project on a ATtiny85 which involves using 433MHz RF modules. Whenever I want to compile any sketch using the Manchester library I always get these errors : "Manchester library doesnt support your microcontroller". Could anyone help me solving this?

Comment: This isn't an electronics problem and has zilch to do with RF.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the tag now.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I got it working. I don't know the cause of the problem but in order to fix it I had to Arduino 1.0 IDE; use [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/arduino-tiny/) ATtiny support and [this](https://github.com/mchr3k/arduino-libs-manchester) Manchester library. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using arduino IDE, only limited functions are supported for the ATtiny85, and if that library requires some of the function from the IDE (Probably Serial), then it will not work. There are few solutions: 1, use an atmega Chip; 2, get another library; 3, write your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution #1 I can not and do not want to use it, since I know it can be done on a ATtiny85; 2: I have tried multiple libraries but all of them give me errors.; 3: I do not have the knowledge to do this.

Comment: The problem originated from the fact that attiny chips lack the hardware UART that all atmega chips have, and the libraries that you have downloaded are probably written for the atmega chips using UART. SO, get the right library is the key; or use the atmega chip; or educate yourself with the knowledge and write your own code.